# Gitbash crashing after I use it to open Jupyter Notebook. Neither gitbash nor jupyter notebook work. jupyter cannot import and gitbash stuck loading

Tags: jupyter-notebook, git-bash

If I try to close then reopen Gitbash, I get the message about no terminal being available. It is completely nonfunctional. And in jupyter notebook, I cannot import packages, which were working fine as of yesterday. I get the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module name" error. I have tried going into task manager as well as the windows command prompt. If I restart my computer, the programs work for a couple minutes then break again.